# Discover the PID of a child process before it starts or after it finished

Tags: process, logs

I wrote a shell script to start a program `${programName}`.

This program happens to creates temporary work files in a folder, `<workFolderLocation>/SAS_work<randomHex>00<pidHex>_<server>`, in which `pidHex` is the hexadecimal representation of the `PID` of the program. Usually this temporary folder disappears when the program finishes.

That program also creates a log file, which I name `${logFolder}/${programName}_$$.log`, so it has the `PID` of the Shell script.

Unfortunately, these pid's are not identical, so if a program does not clean up its work folder, I have no easy way to find the log corresponding to the work folder.

*(I used to solve this by looking into the log file for the pid with `awk` and rename the log file in the script, but unfortunately,  the logs are changed and don't contain the pid anymore.)*

**Edit in response to Stéphane Chazelas**

In the real situation, the log is the standard output of the program. The log name is one of the parameters.

Further, if the program ends with a returncode 1, the script should end with a retunrcode 0, so as not to log an error in our job scheduling system.

Therefore the script currently looks more like:

```
programName=<some calculation>
otherArguments=<other calculation>

"${programName}" -log "$logFolder/${programName}_$$.log" "${otherArguments}"
rc=$?
if [ $rc -eq 1 ]; then
        exit 0
else
        exit $rc
fi
```

Can I still handle the return code after this?

```
exec "${programName}" -log "$logFolder/${programName}_$$.log" "${otherArguments}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
exec "$programName" > "$logFolder/${programName}_$$.log" 2>&1
```

then the program will be executed in the same `$$` process.

That obviously will be the last thing your shell script will do.

If the script needs to do other things afterwards, you can start a new `sh` process that does the redirection and executes the program in the same process:

```
LOGPREFIX="$logFolder/$programName" sh -c '
  exec "$0" "$@" > "${LOGPREFIX}_$$.log" 2>&1
  ' "$progName" and some extra arguments if needed

printf>&2 '%s\n' "$progName terminated with $? exit status"

do-more-stuff-after-the-program-has-returned
```

Or if the rest of the script needs to do something with the pid of the program:

```
LOGPREFIX=$logFolder/$programName sh -c '
  exec "$0" "$@" > "${LOGPREFIX}_$$.log" 2>&1
  ' "$progName" and some args if needed &

pid="$!"
printf>&2 '%s\n' "$progName was started asynchronously with pid $pid"
wait "$pid"
exit_status="$?"
printf>&2 '%s\n' "$progName terminated with exit status $exit_status"
```

Beware that in most shells, starting a command asynchronously has the side effect of redirecting its stdin to /dev/null.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still need to do something after running the program. See my edit to the question . I will elaborate and test this in the real situation next week.